# Unable to connect to Ubuntu from a remote machine

Tags: networking, remote-access, tomcat

In my Ubuntu I installed tomcat and deployed web application.I started tomcat and trying to access from windows like below:

```
http://<54.85.125.1:8080>/manager
```

I am getting output like this:

```
could not connect to 54.85.125.1:8080
```

Then I executed `sudo ufw enable` command, to enable the firewall in Ubuntu, but even though I am still unable to connect to remote machine.

Any one please help me

I executed netstat -a in my cmd

```
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-201:~$ netstat -a
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-20-201.ec:ssh mail.pagesolution:18414 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-20-201.ec:ssh mail.pagesolution:64067 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-20-201.:58381 ec2-54-186-216-161:4505 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    320 ip-172-31-20-201.ec:ssh mail.pagesolution:18178 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-20-201.ec:ssh mail.pagesolution:64065 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8009               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:http-alt           [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 localhost:http-alt      localhost:43938         TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:51788     ip6-localhost:52644     TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:57361     ip6-localhost:57173     TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 localhost:8009          localhost:39078         TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 localhost:49296         localhost:8005          TIME_WAIT
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7432     /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5867     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7250     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  8      [ ]         DGRAM                    7299     /dev/log
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     6070     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     58324    /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_0419609a49f1eec5f4394428f9cebbb5_pub.ipc
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     58326    /var/run/salt/minion/minion_event_0419609a49f1eec5f4394428f9cebbb5_pull.ipc
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     126113
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     126112
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     126092
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     126091
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    125836
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    125830
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     123313
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     123312
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    123174
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     121839
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     121838
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    121700
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11061
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7570     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7569
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7418
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7276     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7275
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7274
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7273
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6557     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6556
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    6110
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    6109
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6045     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6042
```

and executed ps -ax in ubuntu

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-201:~$ ps -ax

4479 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 4480 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 4481 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 4487 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 4579 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
17348 ?        Ss     0:17 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

and also executed telnet localhost 8080 in ubuntu

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-201:~$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I dont have any file like /etc/init.d/tomcatX restart.I started server like below

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-201:~$ sudo /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Comment: 54.85.125.1 is public address and only open port is 22 for ssh. Try to disable ufw `sudo ufw disable` or allow port 8080 `sudo ufw allow 8080`

Comment: i executed commands given by you.still getting could not connect to 54.85.125.1:8080.and i tried run C:\>ping 54.85.125.1

Pinging 54.85.125.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 54.85.125.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\>

Comment: I am trying to connect Ubuntu from windows by giving the http://54.85.125.1:8080/manager

Comment: In my ubuntu installed tomcat and deployed web app and trying to access from my windows by giving http://54.85.125.1:8080/manager.Getting like could not connect to 54.85.125.1:8080.and i tried to execute sudo ufw allow 8080.Still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Ping is not allowed. When I scan ports

```
xxx@xxx ~$ sudo nmap 54.85.125.1 -P0

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-04-15 12:13 CEST
Nmap scan report for ec2-54-85-125-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.85.125.1)
Host is up (0.11s latency).
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 21.42 seconds
```

I see only port 22 is open.
If your service expect connection must on listen state and you can check this with command `netstat -a`.

Example of output well be:

```
xxx@xxx ~ $ netstat -a
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ipp                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:15096                 *:*                     LISTEN
```

If dont have service in listen state, try with `ps -ax` to see is service runing. Also you can ssh to server and try `telnet localhost 8080` to see can you connect to tomcat.

Comment: I pasted my output in the above please find it.Please give me any suggestion to run http://54.85.125.1:8080/manager from my windows browser

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. Give output `netstat -a` from server

Comment: I given the details please find it

Comment: My pc is windows.I given command from Ubuntu(VM which i am accessing using putty).Please clarify me what does the server mean? Is that ubuntu?

Comment: Ok I don't see service on port 8080 in listening state. Only I can tell you is to try to restart service `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcatX restart`. Where X represent your version of tomcat

Comment: I added the details.When i run the netstat -a.The server already started.But,didn't find any port 8080